# Verbatim code chunks with double quotation marks in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, verbatim

As demonstrated in [4.7 Verbatim code chunks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/verbatim-code-chunks.html) in @Yihui 's [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/), we can show a verbatim inline expression,
`` `r knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))")` ``, for example, in our output of RMarkdown.
However, this `knitr::inline_expr()` would not be able to parse a code with double quotation marks, such as
`` `r knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))["(Intercept)", "Estimate"]")` ``.
Then, what should I do when I want to demonstrate the verbatim which contains such a special characters?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "CLRR"
date: "2020/6/20"
documentclass: article
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

This verbatim can appear in the output:

`` `r knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))")` ``

<!--
But, if the code contains `"`, the evaluation fails.

`r knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))["(Intercept)", "Estimate"]")`

```
Quitting from lines 2-16 (test.Rmd) 
Error in parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:1:54: unexpected string constant
1: knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))["(Intercept)", "
                                                         ^
Calls: <Anonymous> ... hook_eval -> withVisible -> eval -> parse_only -> parse
Execution halted
```
-->
````

Comment: have you tried like this: `"coef(summary(model))['(Intercept)', 'Estimate']"` or the other way with quotes: `'coef(summary(model))["(Intercept)", "Estimate"]'`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and especially the latter perfectly works for me! I merged your second way with the answer of @duckmayr .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape the double quotes:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "CLRR"
date: "2020/6/20"
documentclass: article
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: TRUE
---

This verbatim can appear in the output:

`r knitr::inline_expr("coef(summary(model))[\"(Intercept)\", \"Estimate\"]")`
```

[image]

In the comments, @monte provides the other solution, which is alternating single and double quotes: `knitr::inline_expr('coef(summary(model))["(Intercept)", "Estimate"]')`